# How to dynamically rotate the circle on every click using Jquery/Javascript/css?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a CSS class which forms a circle and I am trying to rotate it dynamically from Jquery by adding a css property .It works fine when I click the button for the first time and rest of the time it's idle. I tried using "cssAmination" function and its of no use. I am not able to figure out where I am going wrong. Please help me out in fixing this code. Thanks in advance.

```
/*Circle code*/
div.circle{   
width: 300px;   
height: 300px;    
-moz-border-radius:150px; 
-webkit-border-radius: 150px;  
background:#808080; 
border-radius: 150px;
bottom: -150px;
left: -150px;
position: absolute;
}

/*rotate class*/
div.rotateCircle
{   
/* Firefox: */
-moz-animation-duration: 2s;
-moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
-moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
-moz-animation-play-state: running;
}

@-moz-keyframes moveCircle
{
from {-moz-transform:rotate(0deg);}
to {-moz-transform:rotate(90deg);}
}

//Jquery code:
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
    $("a").click(function(){
        $('div#rotateCircle').css({'-moz-animation-name':'moveCircle'});
    });
}); </script>
<body>
    <h3>Labs Project</h3>
    <div>
        <div id=rotateCircle class="circle">
            &nbsp;
        </div>
        <div id=rotateCircle class="horizontalLine">
            &nbsp;
        </div>
        <div id=rotateCircle class="verticalLine">
            &nbsp;
        </div>
        <div class="divButton">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><a class="btn" href="#">HOME</a></td>
                    <td><a class="btn" href="#">Class</a></td>
                    <td><a class="btn" href="#">CV</a></td>
                    <td><a class="btn" href="#">CM</a></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>      
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Alex, I have edited the body cotent of html to the main post. Thanks.

Comment: You need to put quotes around the div ids `<div id="rotateCircle">`

Comment: I cannot even reproduce the effect you are using once.  I think you should get it working in a http://www.jsfiddle.net example so that you can show us and we can make changes.

Comment: Alex, I got it working on jsfiddle. Please look into it. As I mentioned, the circle (quarter circle) is rotating only for the first click. When I click it for the second time, it isn't working http://jsfiddle.net/kcZBK/

Comment: Here's an article on [restarting CSS animations](http://css-tricks.com/restart-css-animation/) but you can only specify an ID once, you've specified `rotateCircle` three times.

Comment: @alex-w No they are not necessary, but yes, OP should put quotes arround all attributes or none.

Comment: They are just considered good practice in case someone wants to parse your page as XHTML.

Comment: @alex-w The are mandatory if you want to parse it as XML, like the `/` at the end of self closing tags. Anyway, I didn't see that at first but you should NEVER have more than once a element with the same ID, you have 3 `rotateCircle` which is really bad.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look to the JavaScript events for the animations : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/CSS_animations#Using_animation_events

Basically, I've added a class for the animation's name

```
#rotateCircle.rotate {
    -webkit-animation-name: moveCircle;
       -moz-animation-name: moveCircle;
         -o-animation-name: moveCircle;
            animation-name: moveCircle;
}
```

And instead of adding the CSS in jQuery, you just add the class and remove it when the animation is finished, with the `animationend` event :

```
$(function() {
    var $rotateCircle = $('div#rotateCircle');
    $("a").click(function(){
        $rotateCircle.addClass('rotate')
        .on('animationend', function() {
            $rotateCircle.removeClass('rotate');
        });
    });
});
```

(I've made it look a bit nicer too)
Here is [the new working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kcZBK/11/).

NB: The `animationend` event is prefixed on some browser, here is [a gist I've made](https://gist.github.com/2025652) to support all the different browser (you'll need [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com)).

Answer (score 0):

There is a [css3 transition](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_transitions.asp) property that will make this task really simple. I used webkit for my post, change properties accordingly. 
CSS

```
#rotateCircle.rotate {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 2s; //+ optional path i.e. linear
}
```

Then with js, all you need is to set the css property to transition on, and it will magically animate to those settings, in this case transform.

```
$(function() {
    var angle = 0;
    $("a").click(function(){
        angle += 90;
        $("div#rotateCircle").css("-webkit-transform", "rotate("+angle+"deg)";
    });
});
```

I didn't test this code, but the transition property is simple to use, and since I've learned it, I rarely use keyframes/css animation properties anymore.